# How To Assign nil Instead of Exception String

Tags: clojure, try-catch

My question is how can I return a nil from an exception instead of -- in the case of using slurp -- the file name that would not load and the exception text? Here are the details.

I want the following code to return a nil:

```
(defn open-csv-file
    "Attempts to open a .csv file and complains if the file is not present."

    [file-name]
        (let [file-data 
            (try 
                (slurp file-name)
                (catch Exception e (.getMessage e)))]
            file-data))
```

Here is an example of what is being returned now.

```
bene-cmp.core=> (load-file "src/bene_cmp/core.clj")
#'bene-cmp.core/-main
bene-cmp.core=> (def x  (open-csv-file "test_file.csv"))
#'bene-cmp.core/x
bene-cmp.core=> x
"test_file.csv (No such file or directory)"
bene-cmp.core=>
```

I am trying to avoid modifying this function, so that it throws the exception and then having the caller use a try/catch block.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, you just need to change this:

```
(catch Exception e (.getMessage e)))]
```

to this:

```
(catch Exception e))]
```

Comment: Faboo. I cannot find much written about Clojure's try/catch. Thank you.

Comment: As you know, the first two arguments to catch are an Exception class and a symbol to bind to the exception.  Subsequent arguments are just tuples to evaluate in the specified order.  catch's return value is the value of the last tuple.  If there are no tuples, the return value is nil.

Comment: "tuple" is a word that doesn't make sense here - subsequent arguments are just expressions, of any sort. But also, personally I'd suggest writing `nil` to be explicit here, especially if you're unfamiliar with the behavior of `catch`. Nothing wrong with leaving it blank too, of course; that also works.

Comment: Thank you.  I did not realize that in the context of Clojure, "tuple" meant something different from "expression".